# An internal server error has occurred Error ID: 143631613-25605 (-15667340)

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps, gack

I am encountering this ISE error in my Standalone Lightning App. How can I translate this Error ID? Is there an error log or some other way I could check what exactly is wrong? Right now there is no way for me to find out what is wrong. I am new to lightning. Hence, any help/insight on this issue is much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: you will have to contact sf support

Comment: How can I contact sf support? Do you need a premium account for them to offer support?

Comment: No. You can open a case by clicking on "Help" as long as it is not a free developer org. If it is a DE org then you are out of luck. They do not want to hear about bugs from developers who are not paying for a full license. If you are developing for a client have them submit a ticket

Answer (score 15):

I looked up the error in our logs and here is the error message that is unfortunately not being surfaced to you (yes there is already a bug to fix that in the queue - no ETA yet):

org.auraframework.throwable.quickfix.InvalidDefinitionException: Invalid definition for apex://CLInstaller.LoanProductController: Access to entity loan__Fee_Set__c denied: null

Comment: Thanks for assisting the community with this. I wish it were always this easy! Good thing there is not Private Messaging here or your inbox would be flooded lol.

Comment: Hello @Doug-Chasman, I wasn't sure if I should open new thread here but I'm also receiving this error from a managed packaged lightning component. The error code is this: `An internal server error has occurred
Error ID: 1288557852-29109 (-898570520)` - can you also plz confirm if this is the same bug causing this error?

Comment: @doug-chasman - Has you been provided with any workarounds to handle this?

Comment: is this still there? :/

Comment: One cause of `Invalid definition ... Access to entity ... denied` can mean that the Trial license for the package the entity belongs to has expired.

Comment: I really wish there was a way to get this information easier.
I just submitted a Case with SFDC Support - and the agent had no clue what I was talking about - and claimed that there was no issue with SFDC so it must be an issue on my side. 
An internal server error has occurred
Error ID: 251529149-1228089 (-2027637669)

Comment: 2023 is outside -- issue still occurs...

Answer (score 3):

I've noticed when an exception is thrown in the related ApexController of the Lightning component we always get "Internal Server Error" error message. So I can suggest to surround your logic in Apex controller with `try {} catch()` and verify there are no errors in the server-side logic.